# Jira python set custom field

Tags: python, jira, custom-fields, python-jira

I have a problem when I'm trying to set a value on a custom field in JIRA it returns me this error:

```
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 45, in raise_on_error
r.status_code, error, r.url, request=request, response=r, **kwargs)
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400
    text: Operation value must be a string
    url: http://iasp091x.ia.ro.conti.de:8080/rest/api/2/issue/31424
    response headers = {'X-AUSERNAME': 'continental', 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-5132028', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'X-AREQUESTID': '850x418015x3', 'X-ASESSIONID': 'gv7hra', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Date': 'Mon, 01 Feb 2016 12:10:49 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_11301":"Operation value must be a string"}}
```

The code which I'm using is this :

```
new_issue = jira.create_issue(project='PT', summary=issue_summary,
        description=issue_description, issuetype={'name': 'Work'})

new_issue.update(fields={'customfield_11301': [{'value':'test'}]})
```

Custom field 11301 is an input tag in html :

```
<input class="textfield text long-field" id="customfield_11301" name="customfield_11301" maxlength="254" value="" type="text">
```

Any ideea how to make this thing to work ?

Comment: Don't use an array, specify a plain object: `new_issue.update(fields={'customfield_11301': {'value': 'test'}})`

Comment: It's doesn't work. Same error

Comment: Any ideas ?
I think the problem is that the field I want to updated is an input field and I think that it can be updated with json but I don't know how .

Comment: What line is raising the exception exactly? `create_issue()` or `update()`?

Comment: this line `new_issue.update(fields={'customfield_11301': {'value':'test'}})`

Comment: I have another line `new_issue.update(fields={'customfield_11201': [{'value':'User and Group management'}]})` and this  is updated successfully 
In UI Jira this field is a select box

Answer (score 1):

I found an solution:

```
def str_to_utf(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value.decode('latin1')
    return value 



new_issue.update(fields={u'customfield_11301': str_to_utf(user)})
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug to me, raise a bug in jira-python library, with an example that can reproduce it and I will fix it asap.

The library should take care about the encoding and decoding, not you.